# Making a Tree and Sorting out it's numbers

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have a txtfile with a list of unsorted numbers. I took the list of numbers and made an array. So now i'm trying to make a tree with those numbers and sort them out based off of what on the left and right. Right now its printing, but not sorted. I'm pretty sure the tree isn't being made right but I'm not sure how to fix it. I also want to keep track of any duplicates. In other words I don't want to print out any duplicates but instead just keep track of how many there are. Any help or advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance. 
      -- I pass the array of numbers in method: dealArray(), which then converts it to a int. From there those #'s are passed in findDuplicate() which I'm not sure I should  be doing or not.

BigTree Class:

```
       public class bigTree {
 int data; int frequency;
 bigTree Left, Right;


public bigTree makeTree(int x) {
     bigTree p; 
     p = new bigTree();
     p.data = x;
     p.Left = null;
     p.Right = null;
     return p;
 }


 public void setLeft(bigTree t, int x) {

     if (t.Left != null) {
         System.out.println("Error");
     }
     else {
         bigTree q;
         q = t.Left;
         q = makeTree(x);
     }

 }


 public void setRight(bigTree t, int x) {

     if (t.Right != null) {
         System.out.println("Error");
     } else {
         bigTree q;
         q = t.Right;
         q = makeTree(x);
     }
 }

 public void findDuplicate(int number) {
     bigTree tree, p, q;
     frequency = 0;

     tree = makeTree(number);
        //while (//there are still #'s in the list) { //1st while()
            p = tree;
            q = tree;

            while (number != p.data && q != null) { //2nd while()
                p = q; 

                if (number < p.data ) {
                    q = q.Left;
                } else { 
                    q = q.Right;
                }
            } //end of 2nd while()

            if (number == p.data) {
                Sort(p);
                //System.out.println( p.data ); 
                frequency++;
            } 
            else {
                if (number < p.data) {
                    setLeft(p,number);
                }
                else {
                    setRight(p, number);
                }

            }
     //} // End of 1st while()

 }

 public void Sort(bigTree t) {
     if (t.Left != null) {
         Sort(t.Left);
     } 
     System.out.println(t.data); 
     if (t.Right != null) {
         Sort(t.Right);
     }
     //Possible print
     }

 public void dealArray(String[] x) {
    int convert;
     for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
         convert = Integer.parseInt(x[i]);

         findDuplicate(convert);
        // System.out.println(x[i]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: `//Change back to int Dumbass` in your code??

Comment: oh yea haha, earlier for some reason I thought it was a list of names and not numbers so I made everything strings. Sorry bout that

Comment: Now I looked into your code for several minutes but I must confess that I do not get what you are trying to accomplish. For example your `sort` method (please use lower case method/field names but upper case class names) does not do anything except printing your tree. And inside `findDuplicate` you do lots of things which do not make any sense (make a new tree and traverse it - well it's almost empty). Please try to clean your code and get your algorithm working (at least in your head if not inside the code).

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: I'm take the first # off the list and make it the root(the top) of the tree. From there I take the next number off the list, if its greater than the root, I branch off to the right, if its less than the root, than I branch left and so on becomes a big tree. So when the tree is done being made it's passed in the sort method. Now since all the low #'s are go to the left, it's going to go down the tree until tree.left is null which would be the lowest number and would print. The sort method is right, the tree isn't being made correct(which is what I'm having trouble with)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to find duplicates ahead of time, find them while building your Tree.

Your tree should probably consist of a Node like the following:

```
public class Node {
    public int number;
    public int count;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
}
```

Build up your Binary Search Tree (There are a million tutorials on this). While adding a new element, if you find that element already exists, increment your count for that node.

Then printing is a matter of pre-order traversal (Again, there are a million tutorials on this)

Comment: That's not what I'm doing in the findDuplicate() :)

Comment: @TMan: My point is you don't need a `findDuplicate()` method - changing your architecture would dramatically simplify your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the implementation below for hints on how to do it. Sorry I currently cannot format the code and remove the unnecessary methods.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TreeNode implements Iterator , Iterable{  

public Object value;

public TreeNode prev;

public TreeNode left;

public TreeNode right;



private TreeNode w;



public TreeNode(){

}

public TreeNode(Object value){

    this.value= value;

}



public Object[] toArray(){

    Object[] a= new Object[this.size()];

    int i= 0;

    for(Object o : this){

        a[i]= o;

        i++;

    }

    return a;

}



public TreeNode delete(Object o){

    TreeNode z= this.findNode(o);

    if(z==null){

        return this;

    }



    if(z.left != null && z.right != null){

        TreeNode z1= z.right.minNode();

        z.value= z1.value;

        z= z1;

    }



    if(z.left == null && z.right == null){

        TreeNode y= z.prev;

        if(y==null){

            return null;

        }

        if(y.right == z){

            y.right= null;

        }else{

            y.left= null;

        }

        return this;

    }





    if(z.left == null || z.right == null){

        TreeNode y;

        if(z.left != null){

            y= z.left;

        }else{

            y= z.right;

        }

        if(z.prev == null){

            y.prev= null;

            return y;

        }else{

            y.prev= z.prev;

            if(z.prev.left == z){

                z.prev.left= y;

            }else{

                z.prev.right= y;

            }

        }

    }

    return this;

}



public boolean hasNext(){

    return w != null;

}



public Object next(){

    Object d= w.value;

    w= w.nextNode();

    return d;

}



public void remove(){

}



public Iterator iterator(){

    w= this.minNode();

    return this;

}



public Object min(){

    if(this.left == null){

        return this.value;

    }

    return this.left.min();

}



public TreeNode minNode(){

    if(this.left == null){

        return this;

    }

    return this.left.minNode();

}



public Object max(){

    if(this.right == null){

        return this.value;

    }

    return this.right.max();

}



public void print(){

    System.out.println(this.value);

    if(left != null){

        this.left.print();

    }   

    if(right != null){

        this.right.print();

    }       

}   



public void printSort(){

    if(left != null){

        this.left.printSort();

    }   

    System.out.println(this.value);

    if(right != null){

        this.right.printSort();

    }       

}   



public static String intervals(int n, int p){

    String s= "                                                                   ";

    return s.substring(0, n*p);

}



public void printTree(int p){

    printTree0(1, p);

}



public void printTree0(int d, int p){

    if(this.right != null){

        this.right.printTree0(d+1, p);

    }

    System.out.println(intervals(d, p) + this.value);

    if(this.left != null){

        this.left.printTree0(d+1, p);

    }

}



public boolean add(Object o){

    if(this.value.equals(o)){

        return false;

    }

    if( ((Comparable)this.value).compareTo(o) > 0 ){ //left

        if(left != null){

            left.add(o);

        }else{

            left= new TreeNode(o);

            left.prev= this;

        }

    }else{  // right

        if(right != null){

            right.add(o);

        }else{

            right= new TreeNode(o);

            right.prev= this;

        }       

    }

    return true;

}



public void addBalanced(Object o){

    int l= rang(this.left);

    int r= rang(this.right);

    boolean ldir= true;

    if(l == r){

        int ls= size(this.left);

        int rs= size(this.right);

        if(ls > rs){

            ldir= false;

        }

    }else{

        ldir= l <= r;

    }

    if(ldir){

        if(this.left==null){

            this.left= new TreeNode(o);

        }else{

            this.left.addBalanced(o);

        }

    }else{

        if(this.right==null){

            this.right= new TreeNode(o);

        }else{

            this.right.addBalanced(o);

        }           

    }       

}



public TreeNode nextNode(){

    if(this.right != null){

        return this.right.minNode();

    }

    TreeNode t1= this;

    TreeNode t2= this.prev;

    while(t2!=null && t2.right==t1){

        t1= t2;

        t2= t2.prev;

    }

    return t2;

}



public TreeNode findNode(Object o){

    if(this.value.equals(o)){

        return this;

    }

    if( ((Comparable)this.value).compareTo(o) > 0 ){ //left

        if(left != null){

            return left.findNode(o);

        }

    }else{  // right

        if(right != null){

            return right.findNode(o);

        }       

    }

    return null;

}



    public int size(){

    int n= 1;

    if(this.left != null){

        n= n + this.left.size();

    }

    if(this.right != null){

        n= n + this.right.size();

    }

    return n;

}



public static int size(TreeNode t){

    if(t==null){

        return 0;

    }

    return 1 + TreeNode.size(t.left) + TreeNode.size(t.right);

}



public int rang(){

    int l= 0;

    int r= 0;

    if(left!=null){

        l= left.rang();

    }

    if(right!=null){

        r= right.rang();

    }

    return 1 +( (l > r)  ?  l  :  r )   ;

}



public static int rang(TreeNode t){

    if(t==null){

        return 0;

    }

    int l= rang(t.left);

    int r= rang(t.right);

    return 1 +( (l > r)  ?  l  :  r ) ;

}



public String toString(){

    return "( " + value + " " + left + " " + right + " )";  

}
```

/*

```
public String toString(){

    String s= "( " + this.value + " ";



    if(this.left == null && this.right == null){

        return s + ")";

    }



    if(this.left==null){

        s= s + "( )";

    }else{

        s= s + this.left;

    }



    if(this.right==null){

        s= s + "( )";

    }else{

        s= s + this.right;

    }



    return s + ")"; 

}
```

*/

}